# How to find and aggregate in pymongo(MongoDb)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

items:

```json
[{
    "id": 0,
    "studytypes": [{
        "id": 4000,
        "name": "For all",
        "filter": true
      },
      {
        "id": 4001,
        "name": "For girls",
        "filter": false
      },
      {
        "id": 4002,
        "name": "For boys",
        "filter": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "studytypes": [{
        "id": 4000,
        "name": "For all",
        "filter": false
      },
      {
        "id": 4001,
        "name": "For girls",
        "filter": true
      },
      {
        "id": 4002,
        "name": "For boys",
        "filter": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

1. Need to find by `id` and by `filter` pages
2. Need to aggregate by `id` and by `filter` and count all different `id` and `name`s with only `True` `filter`.

```js
db["schools"].find({"$and": [{"studytypes.filter":True}, {"studytypes.id": 4000}]}
```

but it works though all "True" `filter`s without `"id"` difference

Is that a bug or what?

Comment: `$elemMatch` for at least part of what you need

Comment: that really works, but what about aggregation?

Comment: You can use `$elemMatch` in aggregation as well. The rest of the requirements for what you want aren't clear to me. It may involve `$unwind` and `$group`, but personally I'd need to see sample desired output before I could say for sure

Comment: Thaks, at same moment need to mark some moments - 1) we are still using "$match", 2) it must be after "$unwind".

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that comment. In general `$match` does not have to follow `$unwind` depending on what you are trying to do. If your goal is to only retain relevant entries from an array then you can use `$addFields` with `$filter`

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of [using](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) "$and" operator you need to [use](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) "$elemMatch"

`db["schools"].find({"studytypes":{"$elemMatch": {"id":4000,"filter":True}}}))`

2. For aggregate in same way need to [use](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) "$match" operator in pipeline [after](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) "$Unwind" not before and then [sort](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [count](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) it that way

`pipeline = [{"$unwind": "$studytypes"},{"$match": {"studytypes.filter": True}},{"$group": {"_id": {"name": "$studytypes.name", "filter": "$studytypes.filter", "id": "$studytypes.id"},"count": {"$sum": 1}}},{"$sort": SON([("count", -1), ("_id", -1)])}]`

`db["schools"].aggregate(pipeline)`

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).